# Regex extract everything after and before a specific text

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract from this:

```
<meta content=",\n\n\nÓscar Mauricio  Lizcano Arango,\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nBerner León Zambrano Eraso,\n\n\n\n\n" name="keywords"><meta content="Congreso Visible - Toda la información sobre el Congreso Colombiano en un solo lugar" property="og:title"/><meta content="/static/img/logo-fb.jpg"
```

The names shown in there: Óscar Mauricio Lizcano Arango and Berner León Zambrano Eraso.

So it would be something like everything after

```
<meta content="
```

and before

```
name="keywords".
```

Also, using python, I would like to put every name as an element of a list. I would repeat this many times for different strings and the amount of names vary (it could be 4 names instead of 2 as in this case).

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
or_str = '<meta content=",\n\n\nÓscar Mauricio  Lizcano Arango,\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nBerner León Zambrano Eraso,\n\n\n\n\n" name="keywords"><meta content="Congreso Visible - Toda la información sobre el Congreso Colombiano en un solo lugar" property="og:title"/><meta content="/static/img/logo-fb.jpg"'
new_str = or_str.replace("\n","")
li = re.findall('meta content=",(.*)" name="keywords"', new_str);
new_str = ''.join(li)
print re.findall('(.*?),',new_str)
```

I used `replace()` method to change all the newline characters `\n` to `NULL`. 
Then, I used `findall` to look for the names and put it in a list, and again used `findall` to store every name as an element of a list, since `findall` returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it by doing

```
re.findall(r'(?<=content=",)[^.]+(?=name=)', names)
```